# how to check if Field exist in document in firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My [Firestore](https://console.firebase.google.com) Database :

[image: Firestore database screenshot]

i want to check if there is a field named "EmailOf@Follower.com" exist in Doc "D9GeGdTxarFruuuQklEO" only ,, not checking in all docs ,, anyway to do that in [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) [Flutter](http://flutter.io) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know anything at all about the contents of a document, you have to read it and examine its fields.  There is no special operation for checking fields without reading the document.

Comment: It'd be better to have a query like `.where(field_name, '==', null)`. I think that's what he meant. It's really odd to get all 10k records to find out only a few that match this simple condition.

Comment: Cant you do doucmentReference.set({ a: 1 }, { merge: true }) so that if document is nil, the field doesn't get updated? I am not sure if you can do this to check if field is valid, then write. Loved your typescript videos btw! Watched all twice and learned all about promises, async, and Typescript. Thanks!

Comment: orderBy(field_name) is official way for a collection ref, for a doc ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980666/how-to-check-if-a-document-contains-a-property-in-cloud-firestore

Comment: i found this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

Comment: As @Mia, suggest, I'm able to query if a field exist via null. (e.g. `.where('myMap.nestedField', '!=', null)` -> returns documents that have 'myMap.nestedField' existing

Answer (score 9):

From cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0 to up you can check if a particular field exist in a documentSnapshot by doing this:

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
var doc = await users.doc(id).get();
 if(doc.exists){
     Map<String, dynamic> map = doc.data();
     if(map.containsKey('field')){// Replace field by the field you want to check.
       var valueOfField = map['field'];
     }
   }
```

or you can also do this:

```
await _users.doc(id).get().then((doc){
   if(doc.exists){
     doc.data().forEach((key, value) { 
       if(key == 'field'){
         var valueOfField = value;
       }
     });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

issue of using `.where(yourField, '==', null)` is you don't know if yourField actually exists and has `null` value or doesn't exist

if `yourField` is the field that you want to know if it exists,

```
const orderRef = db.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION")
        const docSanpshots = await orderRef.get()
        docSanpshots.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            if (doc.get('yourField') === undefined) {
               // DO SOMETHING HERE when yourField doesn't exist
            }
        })
```

notice that yourField is wrapped with quotes

Comment: Is 'undefined'  keyword is build in or what? It is saying undefined is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I got another solution not mentioned above for who not worked with him the others solution.
the idea is to convert the `Object` data to `Map` type.

so first of all you need to import this

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

in your dart file
then we will encode the object data to get it as Map type

```
jsonEncode(documentSnapshot.data()).contains('your_field')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the extra step to add a `docId` field to every document when it's created, and then use that as the 2nd where condition.  *Would be nice if this was built-in, but not a big deal to implement this workaround if it's needed*

```
bool isSomeFieldSetForUser(String userDocId) {

  final userDb = db.collection('users');
  final firestoreQuery = userDb
      .where('docId', isEqualTo: userDocId)
      .where('someField', isNotEqualTo: null);

  final collection = await firestoreQuery.get();

  if (collection.docs.isEmpty) {
    return false;
  }

  final doc = collection.docs[0];
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the key name to check if it exists against an `undefined` value

```js
const orderSnap = await db.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION").where("user_id","==","01").get();
        
            if (orderSnap.data().yourField == undefined) {
               // DO SOMETHING HERE when yourField doesn't exist
            }
```