# How to check if a document contains a property in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know if there is a way to check if a property is present in a Cloud Firestore document. Something like `document.contains("property_name")` or if there is a document property exist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To solve this, you can simply check the `DocumentSnapshot` object for nullity like this:

```
var yourRef = db.collection('yourCollection').doc('yourDocument');
var getDoc = yourRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
      } else {
        if(doc.get('yourPropertyName') != null) {
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        } else {
          console.log('yourPropertyName does not exist!');
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Dyan! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Alex, sorry... I did but I forgot to mark it as the solution, but worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `in` operator like in the snippet bellow

```
  const ref = admin.firestore().collection('yourCollectionName').doc('yourDocName')
  try {
    const res = await ref.get()
    const data = res.data()    
    if (!res.exists) {
      if (!("yourPropertyName" in data)) {
         // Do your thing
      }
    } else {
         // Do your other thing
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({err: 'Something went terribly wrong'})
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to *making a query*.
Still there is no way to check if some field is present or not in the Firestore. But you can add another field with value *true/false*

```
val query = refUsersCollection
        .whereEqualTo("hasLocation", true)
query.get().addOnSuccessListener { 
      // use the result
  }
```

check out this links for more

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries
[How do I get documents where a specific field exists/does not exists in Firebase Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579693/how-do-i-get-documents-where-a-specific-field-exists-does-not-exists-in-firebase)