# How to handle data that is null in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering how to handle data that is null in firestore?

I'm currently checking that the value I am looking for is null, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
if(!!doc.data().field)
```

But this is very verbose for many fields.

Comment: You have to check for null, that is part of the game of programming, no way around and nothing wrong with it, no matter how dogmatic some intelligent software engineers get about null values

Comment: would this help you? [How to check if a document contains a property in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980666/how-to-check-if-a-document-contains-a-property-in-cloud-firestore), where property is the field that you are looking into.

Answer (score 1):

i prefer this way

```
if(doc.data().field != null && typeof doc.data().field != 'undefined' && !isNaN(doc.data().field ))
```